# how to get content of file which are using require when auto importing node_moduels package?

Tags: angularjs, gulp-inject, gulp-livereload

I am using angular 1.6 and gulp with live reload and babel to run a development server. Installing all angular packages using yarn so using npmfiles to automate import dependencies in index.html.

all packages being added in final index.html on proper place but that file only have the content the respective index.js which is mentioned in the node_modules/package/package.json "main: attributes

for eg. adding angular library. final .tmp/index.html has below content

```
<script src="/../node_modules/angular/index.js"></script>
```

but this *angular/index.js* have the following content

```
 require('./angular');
 module.exports = angular;
```

BUT I want the content of angular js file

also, it gives multiple errors in the console for each package

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index.js:1

here is the relevant code

```
gulp.task('connectDev', function() {
    connect.serverClose();
    connect.server({
        name: 'Zeus:Dev',
        root: [path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src],
        port: 3000,
        debug: false,
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        fallback: path.resolve('./.tmp/serve/index.html'),
        livereload: true,
        directoryListing: false,
        middleware: function(connect) {
            return [connect().use('/node_modules', connect.static('node_modules'))];
        }
    });
});
```

and  using this task  I am adding all node_modules libray

```
 var npmVendors = gulp.src(mainNPMFiles( {nodeModulesPath: '../node_modules/'} ));
  // .pipe($.babel({"presets": ["env"]}));

  var npmOptions = {
    relative: true,
    starttag: '<!-- inject:ang:{{ext}} -->',
    ignorePath: [conf.paths.src, path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')],
    addRootSlash: true,
    // transform: function (filePath, file) {
    //     return file.contents.toString('utf8');
    // }
  };
```

in src/index.html

```
<!-- inject:ang:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

now if I uncomment the *transform* property it add the content of file directly in index.html without `<sctipt>` tag

SO my question is how to add the original content of file rather than the 2 lines of index.js

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't understand require statements. You will have to use Dependency bundling tools like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or webpack with gulp.

Add one more task in gulp to browserify your dependencies and it will automatically capture your full source and vendor code

You can use browserify plugins for gulp.

**UPDATE**

I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/agabhane/gulp-browserify-setup-angularjs) for you. Please have a loo

Comment: Will you help me how to add and where to add?  I do not want to use webpack

Comment: where to insert the browesrify? inside npmOption or npmVendors? [here](https://pastebin.com/DcCZ0arF) is the complete file of the relevant gulp task

Comment: @pro.mean Are you okay with using bower package manager. Installing angular using bower will not create such issues and you can easily load your bower files to index.html.

Comment: I want to get away from bower and that is the main reason I have changed my code in this way. bower drop its support. otherwise, bower was working fine with wiredep

Comment: I am in the same situation.

Comment: @Ashish Thanks. Tomorrow I'll try to use both browserify and mainNPMFiles.

Comment: Thanks alot @Ashish for the help. I will check the code and will accept the answer once get the positive outcome.